# Algorithm to partition graph into complete subgraphs

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, data-science

I need an algorithm to partition the vertices of an undirected graph into one or more subgraphs, such that each subgraph is a complete graph (every vertex adjacent to every other vertex). Each vertex needs to be in exactly one of the subgraphs.

Here's an example:

```py
input = [
    (A, B),
    (B, C),
    (A, C),
    (B, D),
    (D, E),
]
output = myalgo(input)  # [(A, B, C), (D, E)]
```

Here's an image that better describes the problem:

[image: example]

The input list is sorted in decreasing order by distance, that's why I connect A-B-C instead of B-D.

I thought this might be called "strongly connected components", and have already tried the following solutions:

- [Finding a Strongly Connected Components in unDirected Graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44594132/finding-a-strongly-connected-components-in-undirected-graphs): it's looking for something different
- [Finding all cycles in undirected graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12367801/finding-all-cycles-in-undirected-graphs): it gives me *many* cycles and not the best, it doesn't care about the input order.
- [An algorithm to create clusters from data pairs in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35021792/an-algorithm-to-create-clusters-from-data-pairs-in-python/35021895): it connects all the components, just because there is a path between them (A-B-C-D-E).
- [Kosaraju's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kosaraju%27s_algorithm): it works only with a directed graph.

Comment: by "strong connection" you mean "all elements within the component must be directly linked to each other"?

Comment: @LukasThaler yes

Comment: Sounds like a fun exercise. Let me see what I can come up with :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a class that implements the segmentation into complete subgraphs. It's by no means optimized and can likely be improved significantly, but it's a starting point

```py
class SCCManager:
    def __init__(self, edges):
        self.clusters = []
        self.edges = edges

    def clusters_in(self, conn):
        first, second = conn
        f_clust = None
        s_clust = None
        for i, clust in enumerate(self.clusters):
            if first in clust:
                f_clust = i
            if second in clust:
                s_clust = i
            # break early if both already found
            if f_clust and s_clust:
                break
        return (f_clust, s_clust)

    def all_connected(self, cluster, vertex):
        for v in cluster:
            connected = (v, vertex) in self.edges or (vertex, v) in self.edges
            # break early if any element is not connected to the candidate
            if not connected:
                return False
        return True

    def get_scc(self):
        for edge in self.edges:
            c_first, c_second = self.clusters_in(edge)

            # case 1: none of the vertices are in an existing cluster
            # -> create new cluster containing the vertices
            if c_first == c_second == None:
                self.clusters.append([edge[0], edge[1]])
                continue

            # case 2: first is in a cluster, second isn't
            # -> add to cluster if eligible
            if c_first != None and c_second == None:
                # check if the second is connected to all cluster components
                okay = self.all_connected(self.clusters[c_first], edge[1])
                # add to cluster if eligible
                if okay:
                    self.clusters[c_first].append(edge[1])
                continue

            # case 3: other way round
            if c_first == None and c_second != None:
                okay = self.all_connected(self.clusters[c_second], edge[0])
                if okay:
                    self.clusters[c_second].append(edge[0])
                continue

            # case 4: both are in different clusters
            # -> merge clusters if allowed
            if c_first != c_second:
                # check if clusters can be merged
                for v in self.clusters[c_first]:
                    merge = self.all_connected(self.clusters[c_second], v)
                    # break if any elements are not connected
                    if not merge:
                        break
                # merge if allowed
                if merge:
                    self.clusters[c_first].extend(self.clusters[c_second])
                    self.clusters.remove(self.clusters[c_second])

            # case 5: both are in the same cluster
            # won't happen if input is sane, but doesn't require an action either way


        return self.clusters
```

... and here's a working example:

```py
inp = [
    ('A', 'B'),
    ('B', 'C'),
    ('A', 'C'),
    ('B', 'D'),
    ('D', 'E'),
    ('C', 'E')
]

test = SCCManager(inp)
print(test.get_scc())

[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 'E']]
```

Comment: Say the input is a large clique with one edge removed. Correct answers are all vertex partitions that separate the vertices of the missing edge. Which would you prefer?

Comment: That is dictated by user input. The OP mentions in their question that the order the edges are given in matters. If the (B,D) edge in the above graph was the first to be input, we would end up with the components (A,C) and (B,D), (and (E), if you want to consider that a component, which my implementation as of now doesn't)

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import defaultdict


def create_adjacency_matrix(connections):
    matrix = defaultdict(dict)
    for a, b in connections:
        matrix[a][b] = 1
        matrix[b][a] = 1
    return matrix


def is_connected_to_all(vertex, group, matrix):
    for v in group:
        if vertex != v and vertex not in matrix[v]:
            return False
    return True


def group_vertexes(input):
    matrix = create_adjacency_matrix(input)
    groups = []
    current_group = set()
    for vertex in matrix.keys():
        if is_connected_to_all(vertex, current_group, matrix):
            current_group.add(vertex)
        else:
            groups.append(current_group)
            current_group = {vertex}
    groups.append(current_group)
    return groups
```

```
input = [("A", "B"), ("B", "C"), ("A", "C"), ("B", "E"), ("E", "D")]
print(group_vertexes(input))
# [{'C', 'B', 'A'}, {'D', 'E'}]
```

WARNING: This relies on the fact that dict keeps insertion order in python 3.7+. In older versions you have to use `matrix = DefaultOrderedDict(dict)` https://stackoverflow.com/a/35968897/9392216:

Comment: The matrix is a sweet idea, but the algorithm breaks if I add another ('C', 'E') to the input. I think the update logic needs to be a little more robust to deal with more complex inputs

Comment: Could you provide the whole wrong input, because I tested it and it works for ('C','E') at the end of current input.

Comment: `inp = [('A', 'B'),('B', 'C'),('A', 'C'),('B', 'D'),('D', 'E'),('C', 'E')]` results in `[{'B', 'C', 'A'}, {'E', 'D'}, {'E', 'C'}]` for me

Comment: So you probably use python version lower than 3.7, because i rely on dict keeping the insertion order

Comment: Running on 3.7, actually. What output do you get for this input?

Comment: Yeah, you're right :P. I was running modified version with `for vertex in matrix.keys():` which was an alternative option in my answer. I modified the first one to use correct logic.

Answer (score 1):

Another attempt:

```
lst = [
    ('A', 'B'),
    ('B', 'C'),
    ('A', 'C'),
    ('B', 'D'),
    ('D', 'E'),
]

d = {}
for i, j in lst:
    d.setdefault(i, []).append(j)
    d.setdefault(j, []).append(i)

from itertools import combinations

rv, seen_segments, seen_vertices = [], set(), set()
for k, v in d.items():
    if len(v) == 1:
        segment = set((k, v[0])).difference(seen_vertices)
        seen_vertices.update(segment)
        rv.append([tuple(segment), ])
    else:
        graph = []
        for i, j in combinations([k] + v, 2):
            if not j in d[i]:
                break
            else:
                graph.append(tuple(sorted((i, j))))
        else:
            if graph:
                graph = [segment for segment in graph if segment not in seen_segments]
                seen_segments.update(graph)
                if graph:
                    rv.append(graph)

from pprint import pprint
pprint(rv)
```

Prints:

```
[[('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('B', 'C')], [('D', 'E')]]
```

---

For input

```
lst = [
    ('A', 'B'),
    ('B', 'C'),
]
```

Prints:

```
[[('A', 'B')], [('C',)]]
```

---

For input:

```
lst = [
    ('A', 'B'),
    ('B', 'C'),
    ('C', 'D'),
]
```

Prints:

```
[[('B', 'A')], [('D', 'C')]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find all paths, and then group by connectivity:

```
from itertools import groupby as gb
d = [('A', 'B'), ('B', 'C'), ('A', 'C'), ('B', 'D'), ('D', 'E')]
def connect_num(node):
    return [sum(a == node for a, _ in d), sum(b == node for _, b in d)]

def group_paths(data):
   new_d = sorted([[i, connect_num(i)] for i in data], key=lambda x:max(x[1]))
   return [[k for k, _ in b] for _, b in gb(new_d, key=lambda x:max(x[1]))]

def get_paths(start, c = [], seen = []):
   new_vals = [a for a, _ in d if a not in seen+c]
   if (vals:=[b for a, b in d if a == start]):
      for i in vals:
         yield from get_paths(i, c=c+vals, seen=seen)
   else:
      yield c
      for i in new_vals:
         yield from get_paths(i, c = [i], seen=c+seen)

result = sorted(map(set, get_paths(d[0][0])), key=len, reverse=True)
new_result = [a for i, a in enumerate(result) if not any(all(k in c for k in a) for c in result[:i])]
final_result = [group_paths(i) for i in new_result]
```

Output:

```
#final_result[0]
[['E', 'D'], ['A', 'C', 'B']]
```